# Laravel Blank Screen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a Laravel app. It was working nicely. But today it only shows a blank white screen. It seems like not responding but it responds nothing. **There is no log, no error.**

When I tried the code bellow, I also got a blank screen.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return "hello";
});
```

In `index.php`

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
AFTER THIS POINT IT IS NOT WORKING
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0"
```

Tried manual debugging. Php works, but the Laravel app is not working.

Comment: There is something on a controller not working for you, maybe a middleware, but `index.php` has nothing to do with the possible issue

Comment: Do not post the solution in your question; there is a decicated answers section below that you can post your solution. However, this this essentially equates to a typo (or local issue), you're better off simply deleting this question altogether. Also, I won't even go into the dangers of modifying your `.env` file from a Route like this, but be careful with this kind of logic; the `.env` file should ideally be static; if you need to modify something at runtime, you can use the `config()->set(...)` logic, since `config` values are populated from your `.env` anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a route in code /test which sets env variable(this key value pair **fff=123**) to .env file.

and somebody must visited /test url. Then .env file has been changed like bellow.

```
AWS_BUCKET="my-s3application"fff=123
```

as you can see there is 2 equal sign and this lets laravel blank screen error.

have a good day